# Convert vowel to integer and integer to vowel

Tags: python-3.x

I'm completing a task with two functions, `encode` and `decode`. `encode` is to convert all vowels in a string to their corresponding numbers (see dictionary in code), and `decode` is to convert all integers in a string back to their corresponding vowels.

My code so far:

```
vowels = {'a': '1',
          'e': '2',
          'i': '3',
          'o': '4',
          'u': '5'}


def encode(word1):
    new_word = ""
    for letter in word1:
        if letter.lower() not in vowels:
            new_word += letter
        else:
            new_word += letter.replace(letter, vowels[letter])

    return new_word


print(encode('hello'))


def decode(word2):
    new_word1 = ""
    for letter in word2:
        if letter.lower()not in vowels:
            new_word1 += letter
        elif letter.isdigit():
            new_word1 += letter.replace(letter, vowels[letter])

    return new_word1


print(encode('h2ll4'))

----------------------------------------------
>>> h2ll4
>>> h2ll4
```

I've managed to do the first function `encode` but can't quite manage to get the second one right. I attempted to get the `key` to return a `value` for `encode`, but can I get the `value` to return a `key` for `decode`?

My questions:

- Can I get a dictionary `value` to return the `key`, just as the `key`
  can return the `value`?
- How can I check for integers in a string (1
  to 5) and then return the vowel?
- Also, what approach would be the
  most Pythonic way to do this? Can my `encode` function be shorter?

You may assume that the only integers to appear in a string are 1 to 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise way to do this is to use a list comprehension, checking if each character in `word` is in `vowels` and if so, replacing it with the corresponding integer. Decoding can be done the same way with the use of an inverse dictionary:

```
vowels = {'a': '1',
          'e': '2',
          'i': '3',
          'o': '4',
          'u': '5'}

inv_vowels = { i : v for v, i in vowels.items() }

def encode(word):
    return ''.join(vowels[c] if c in vowels else c for c in word)

def decode(word):
    return ''.join(inv_vowels[c] if c in inv_vowels else c for c in word)

print(encode('hello'))

print(decode(encode('hello')))
```

Output:

```
h2ll4
hello
```

If you want to allow for uppercase letters in `word`, you can replace `c` in the list comprehension with `c.lower()` i.e.

```
def encode(word):
    return ''.join(vowels[c.lower()] if c.lower() in vowels else c for c in word)
```

but be aware that on decode the encoded vowel will always be translated to a lower case character i.e.

```
print(decode(encode('HEllo')))
```

gives

```
Hello   # not HEllo
```

You can work around that by expanding the dictionary to include upper case vowels and not changing the case of the input letters e.g.

```
vowels = {'a': '1',
          'e': '2',
          'i': '3',
          'o': '4',
          'u': '5',
          'A': '6',
          'E': '7',
          'I': '8',
          'O': '9',
          'U': '0'}

inv_vowels = { i : v for v, i in vowels.items() }

def encode(word):
    return ''.join(vowels[c] if c in vowels else c for c in word)

def decode(word):
    return ''.join(inv_vowels[c] if c in inv_vowels else c for c in word)

print(encode('HEllo'))

print(decode(encode('HEllo')))
```

Output:

```
H7ll4
HEllo
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, That's exactly what I was hoping to find out